# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post') Run time error in Next JS 13

Tags: next.js13

- Hello Everyone!
- I have downloaded a git repository https://github.com/Akiletour/inrage and setup with WordPress,
- Next JS and GraphQL.
- 
- I am able to see the blog listing page at frontend but not able to see the single blog page, it
- is showing an error "Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')".
- 
- My single Post GraphQL query is:
- 
- I am using GraphQL for ACF, WPGraphQL, ACF plugins in the WordPress. I have created a group
- field via ACF with three fields: title (text), metadesc (textare) and canonical (url).
- 
- I have created few default posts with above three fields in each post.
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/veJcs.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrccM.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuyIQ.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J7jd.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK13n.png

`query getSingleArticle($id: ID!) { post(id: $id) { id title databaseId slug date excerpt content(format: RENDERED) featuredImage { node { sourceUrl } } seo { title metaDesc canonical } } posts { edges { node { title slug date excerpt featuredImage { node { sourceUrl } } } } } }`

- Can anyone help me please, I want to see the single details page.